# The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the server and try

Tags: dji-sdk

```
DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
              new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                         Log.v(AAAAAAAA, djiError.getDescription());
                    }
```

I made sure that I was connected to the Internet. It was good before, but suddenly I started reporting this error. Every time I register, it prompts me that The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the server and try. Sometimes there is very little The registration may be successful. I tried to change the account and key of D, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you set the bundle id correctly when you created the API key? As per [this question](https://phantompilots.com/threads/activation-failed-please-retry-phantom-4-pro.122824/), the full error seems to be

```
Sdk Registration Failed. Please check the bundle ID and your network 
connectivity.The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the 
server and try
```

If that's not the issue, [in the past people have opened an issue](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio/issues/7) that appears to be fixed over a year ago. You may need to contact DJI support.

Answer (score 1):

To get a DJI AppKey you went to https://developer.dji.com/ and declared a new application with a bundle identifier:

[image]

You have to declare the exact name of your project package:

[image]

And use this AppKey (in AndroidManifest.xml) only for this project.

I encountered your problem when trying to use the same AppKey for different packages... Ensuring I respected the association AppKey / bundle id fixed it.